# New Intent - requireActivity() and requireContext()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

What is the difference between **requireActivity()** and **requireContext()** when starting a new Activity Intent

```
startActivity(Intent(requireContext(), A::class.java))

startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), B::class.java))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fragment theoretically can be attached to a Context that is not an Activity. In this case `requireActivity()` would throw an Exception when `requireContext()` wouldn't.

You would know if you were using a Fragment in this unconventional way, so for all *intents* and purposes, there is no practical difference.

`requireContext()` is returning the same Activity instance as `requireActivity()` would, but it is upcast to Context. An Activity would be implicitly upcast to Context anyway when you pass it to the `Intent` constructor, since it is expecting a Context.

Answer (score 1):

**requireActivity()** a method that returns the non-null activity instance to fragment or throws an exception. If you are 100% sure that in your fragment's lifecycle, activity is not null

**requireContext()** returns a nonnull Context , or throws an exception when one isn't available.